# How to manage Google OAuth with existing email and password login mechanism?

Tags: android, node.js, postgresql, oauth, google-one-tap

I have an app that is currently using email and password for account authentication. Whenever the user logs in using email and password, the backend creates a JWT session token and returns it to the app.

This works well. Now, I am trying to integrate Google One-tap sign-in[OAuth] and I want to keep my existing login system too.

I am not able to figure out how to manage the session/authentication for the user in the database. My existing user table has:

`Name, email, password, ...`

In the case of OAuth, I will only get the email and token. Once I validate the token then I will have no password to save. So, is it alright to just save OAuth unique id for the user in an `external_unique_id` column and do nothing with the password (as in leave it blank)?

Kindly, help me with understanding how to manage this sort of system.
Especially, how to handle the flow when the user tries to sign in the second time when the `external_unique_id` is already existing.
Should I compare the unique id received from the OAuth provided with the `external_unique_id`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if its the best approach but you can create a new column in your user table that tells you what login method user used (in this case, google or api).
You dont really need google unique id, you just need to know the authentication was successful to generate a new token or not.
On the first authentication you need to create a new user based on google payload. In the next ones, just get the user on database using his email and do whatever you need to.

Comment: Thanks!
Seems like a good path to go for. I am going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

We have serveral method to make authentication,

1. Authorization Server generate token and auth tokens:
   Client need to get token from server by inputing credential, the server send back a token. Each time, application need to connect auth server to make authentication
2. Authorization server share database with other application
   Once the user get token from auth. server. He can use it in other resource server. This resource server directly fetch tokens from database and make authentication by itself.
3. Use JWT to authorize.
   Client get generated Jwt token from auth. server. Auth server may share public key to other resource server. The resource server can use public key to decode content. Since only authorization server has private key, only auth.server can generate correct jwt content

In my opinion, you need to create a new user in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am trying to understand is how to manage the database schema and authentication mechanism.
For managing external unique id and password (In case of existing login system)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I edit a new anwser for it

Comment: Thank you for explaining all the above options. I am going to use the first option!